# Mysql optimization algorithm , variants to saving changes in history

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, bigdata

I got one main table with actual user info

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
  id                            bigint                              NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY,
  updated                       timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  username                      varchar(40)                         NULL,
  full_name                     varchar(255)                        NULL,
  biography                     varchar(512)                        NULL,
  profile_pic_id                varchar(40)                         NULL,
  profile_pic_url               varchar(255)                        NULL,
  hd_profile_pic_url            varchar(255)                        NULL,
  follower_count                int                                 NULL,
  following_count               int                                 NULL,
  media_count                   int                                 NULL,
  usertags_count                int                                 NULL,
  following_tag_count           int                                 NULL,
  external_url                  longtext                            NULL,
  reel_auto_archive             varchar(255)                        NULL,
  has_biography_translation     tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  has_anonymous_profile_picture tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  has_highlight_reels           tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  is_business                   tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  is_active                     tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  is_verified                   tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  is_private                    tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  is_blocked                    tinyint(1)                          NULL
)
```

Also almost same table for saving history:

```
CREATE TABLE user_history
(
  id                            int AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id                  bigint                              NULL,
  added                         timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  username                      varchar(40)                         NULL,
  full_name                     varchar(255)                        NULL,
  biography                     varchar(512)                        NULL,
  profile_pic_id                varchar(40)                         NULL,
  profile_pic_url               varchar(255)                        NULL,
  hd_profile_pic_url            varchar(255)                        NULL,
  follower_count                int                                 NULL,
  following_count               int                                 NULL,
  media_count                   int                                 NULL,
  usertags_count                int                                 NULL,
  following_tag_count           int                                 NULL,
  external_url                  longtext                            NULL,
  reel_auto_archive             varchar(255)                        NULL,
  has_biography_translation     tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  has_anonymous_profile_picture tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  has_highlight_reels           tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  is_business                   tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  is_active                     tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  is_verified                   tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  is_private                    tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  is_blocked                    tinyint(1)                          NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_F19A7E3C5AFE2D44
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id)
)
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE INDEX IDX_F19A7E3C5AFE2D44
  ON user_history (user_id);
```

Ang tigger for saving history:

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_update
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON user
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `user_history` (`user_id`, `username`, `full_name`, `biography`, `profile_pic_id`,
                                   `profile_pic_url`, `hd_profile_pic_url`, `follower_count`, `following_count`,
                                   `media_count`, `usertags_count`, `following_tag_count`, `external_url`,
                                   `reel_auto_archive`, `has_biography_translation`, `has_anonymous_profile_picture`,
                                   `has_highlight_reels`, `is_business`, `is_active`, `is_verified`, `is_private`,
                                   `is_blocked`, `added`)
  VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.username, NEW.full_name, NEW.biography, NEW.profile_pic_id, NEW.profile_pic_url,
          NEW.hd_profile_pic_url,
          NEW.follower_count, NEW.following_count, NEW.media_count, NEW.usertags_count, NEW.following_tag_count,
          NEW.external_url,
          NEW.reel_auto_archive, NEW.has_biography_translation, NEW.has_anonymous_profile_picture,
          NEW.has_highlight_reels,
          NEW.is_business, NEW.is_active, NEW.is_verified, NEW.is_private, NEW.is_blocked, now());
END;
```

So I had some questions:

1. Any variant to improve writing speed to saving history?
   I try via LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, not trigger - no speed improvements.
2. Any variants to saving history with less datasize?
   For example I think I can run some external script, that check user_history data and set NULL for same values?
   I try to use another trigger for saving - bigger, which compare every value before writing and write only changed values - but its quite long for execution.
   Or any better variant to saving diff of data(reuseble) to db?

Comment: [System versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-versioned-tables/)

Comment: @danblack looks like this feature only MariaDB, am I right? I use Mysql 8.0

Comment: In MySQL there is no support for temporal table like danblack sent.

Comment: Clarification:  Is this correct:  `user` always contains the _current_ values and `user_history` has a complete history?

Answer (score 0):

- Move counters to a parallel table.  Just splitting these out will also speed up the `UPDATE`.  The internal processing of "UPDATE" involves building a copy of the entire row in case some other connection is accessing the same row.
- Additionally, don't keep a history on them.  I would guess that the majority of "updates" are in this area.
- Combine all the `has_%` and `is_%` flags into a single `SET` or `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (for up to 8, or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` for up to 16).
- Don't have `has` flags -- simply use `LEFT JOIN` or `EXISTS` when you need to check for "has".
- Make `is_%` flags (and probably other columns) `NOT NULL`.  In general, you should consciously decide whether `NULL` is meaningful to the business logic, not simply have all the columns be `NULLable`.

(My suggestions apply to all versions of MySQL and MariaDB.)